# Collections of F-bound polymorphic objects

Tags: scala, f-bounded-polymorphism

Say I have an F-bounded polymorphic trait:

```
sealed trait FBound[Me <: FBound[Me]]
case class A() extends FBound[A]
case class B() extends FBound[B]
```

How can I use it if I have a collection that can be any instance?

```
val canBeEither: Option[FBound[_]] = Some(B())

// error: type arguments [_$1] do not conform to trait FBound's type parameter bounds [Me <: FBound[Me]]
canBeEither.collect({ case b: B => b}).foreach(b => println("got a B!"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use this type

```
T forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }
// equivalent
FBound[T] forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }
```

To represent "some `FBound` object". In your case

```
val canBeEither: Option[T forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }] = Some(B())
canBeEither.collect { case b: B => b }.foreach(println)
```

You probably should always avoid pulling the binder out of the type constructor application. E.g. for `List`:

```
val eithers: List[T forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }]
  = List[T forSome { type <: FBound[T] }](A(), B()) // ok
val eithers: List[T] forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }
  = List[ThereIsNothingThatCanGoHere](A(), B()) // not ok
```

So you may want to say

```
type SomeFBound = T forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }
```

And use `SomeFBound` everywhere.

Comment: This "probably" part seems suspicious. `List[T] forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }` is just as valid / useful as the `List[T forSome { type T <: FBound[T] }]`. It simply enforces that all elements of the list have *the same* (unknown) type.

Comment: Indeed, but if you want to have a type that means "some kind of `FBound`, I don't care which", you really should stick to `SomeFBound` and avoid moving the `forSome` clause. It's important to note the difference because floating the `forSome` into the wrong place is easy.

Answer (score 3):

That would be

```
val canBeEither: Option[X forSome { type X <: FBound[X] }] = Some(B())
```

but I'd urge you to think twice before using this in your code. It will also give you a bunch of warnings about existential types, which you would have to silence by importing `scala.language.existentials`.

Comment: And this syntax is going away in Scala 3.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes. To avoid existential quantification, one could introduce an extra class with a proper type member: `trait FBound[X <: FBound[X]]; trait SomeFBound { type X <: FBound[X]; val value: X } ; val canBeEither: Option[SomeFBound] = None`

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon So what would be `canBeEither`s type in Dotty/Scala3?

Comment: Apparantly path-dependent types are the recommendation to use in most use cases instead

Comment: @dtech There is nothing path dependent about `SomeFBound` above. It would be path-dependent only if you had a type that depends on a value, like `x.T`, where `x` is some value. In `trait SomeFBound { type X <: FBound[X] }`, the `X` type is just an ordinary, non-path-dependent member. That's sufficient to replace `forSome`, but requires an extra trait / class declaration that is responsible for holding the type member `X`.